# External images not being displayed in Android app - Meteor - Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I am developing an android app using Meteor and am having problems displaying images from external sources.

The following `<img>` tag should displays an image from the google maps api based on the latitude and longitude:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{loc.lat}},{{loc.lng}}&zoom=15&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7C{{loc.lat}},{{loc.lng}}" />
```

Though this works in the browser, I get the below error on the server when trying to run it on an android device

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.0.2.2:3000/sockjs/info?cb=p4ej3xginv. Origin http://meteor.local is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Do I need to put the 'google maps api' domain in some kind of 'Whitelist' like when working with Phonegap.

If so, how do we do this in Meteor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, starting from 1.0.4, ["Meteor Cordova apps no longer allow access to all domains by default."](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2015/03/17/meteor-104-mongo-cordova-template-subscriptions)

So from now on, in your `mobile-config.js` file, you will have to call [App.accessRule](https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html#App-accessRule) for every external domain you may load content from.

So in your case, adding:

```
App.accessRule('http://maps.googleapis.com/*');
```

at the end of your `mobile-config.js` file should do the trick.

Comment: or if you want to allow all `App.accessRule("*");`

Answer (score 4):

Adding access rules to mobile-config.js fixes loading of external images in Cordova apps.

1. Create a **mobile-config.js** file in your project root
2. Add `App.accessRule('https://www.mycdn.com/*');`
3. Build and run your app `meteor run ios`

This is an alternative option, my guess is there might be some difference how this is built:

1. Create a folder **cordova-build-override** in your project root
2. Copy **config.xml** from *.meteor/local/cordova-build* to your newly created *cordova-build-override* folder
3. Add external origin servers as needed `<access origin="https://www.mycdn.com/*"/>`
4. Build and run your app `meteor run ios`

Initially I was trying with *[browser-policy](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/browser-policy)* package and setting `BrowserPolicy.content.allowImageOrigin("https://www.mycdn.com/*");`, but apparently that is a different story?